# What's the most absurd myth about programming issues?

Tags: experience, self-improvement, code-quality, mistakes

To put it another way... What is the most commonly held and frustrating misunderstanding about programming, you have encountered?

Which widespread and longstanding myths/misconceptions do you find **hard for programmers to dispel/correct**.

Please, explain why this is a myth.

Comment: I'd like to see Mythbusters take on some of these.

Comment: Anyone up for a Mythbuggers YouTube channel? :-)

Comment: Ooooh, MythBusters and race conditions!  Meesa like!

Comment: @TomWij that would be great to have a website with such name!

Answer (score 272):

That because you're a programmer, you know how to fix [person]'s virus ridden machine.

Comment: No kidding.  My wife is always volunteering me to fix her friends' stuff

Comment: totally agree with this one!

Comment: LOLI agree! And it usually extends to because you are a programmer you can configure my dvr...

Comment: Car analogy / get out clause: "I'm a racing driver not a mechanic."

Comment: Me: "I can try but it is not my specialty"    Them: "You work with computers don't you?  Can't you just like re-program it or something?"  Me:  Sigh.....

Comment: I get this one a lot, too...  My response:  "I *used* to do that kind of thing, but I really didn't enjoy it, so now I'm a programmer."

Comment: Oh my god... I've just fixed TV of my landlord, and now spotted *that*...

Comment: This comic is relevant: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/computers

Comment: http://xkcd.com/627/

Comment: @Tim if she can cook, start volunteering her to cater your friends' parties

Comment: @Peter Very nice!!! I'll have to remember that one :-)

Comment: Its not that I don't know how to... It that I don't want to waste hours fixing your machine that you will break in 2 weeks anyway.

Comment: I definitely agree that the two are different sets of skills, but I must admit that I feel a bit disapproving of this attitude. I fail to see how a programmer can use a computer without the desire to be a power user.

Comment: To be fair... I DO know how to fix their machine 99% of the time

Comment: My friend wants me update his mobile phone (a duplicate one that he bought at 20% of the original price) so that it works just like the original. Sigh!

Comment: EpsilonVector - unfortunately, there are *plenty* of programmers like that. :( For those that aren't, it's more a case of what ChaosPandion says. Personally, I'll help immediate family, but beyond that I'll just give generic advice pointing in the right direction.

Comment: I do believe this is on the verge of winning the site's first "Great Answer" badge.  C'mon, two more votes, you can do it....

Comment: you should bold that 'windows' word :D

Comment: So true,  most programmers don't understand security at all.  That is why we have vulnerabilities that viruses use to spread.

Comment: It's easy - reinstall Windows!

Comment: This times 10,000. Computer science != tech support. I need to get this shirt: http://www.thinkgeek.com/tshirts-apparel/unisex/frustrations/388b/

Answer (score 266):

A common HR thing that drives me nuts when I'm job hunting: the implicit assumption that all coding skills are language-specific, that there is no software engineering expertise that transcends command sets.  That ten years experience in Java and another five in Perl mean you'd be completely useless on a project that uses, say, C#.

"Yes, there's a learning curve.  But I've made harder transitions than this.  I'll make you a deal, pay me 80% for the first month and at the end of that time if I'm not ... oh, wait, we're not actually having this conversation, because your HR monkey simply deleted my application."

Comment: +INF for HR monkey.

Comment: I have had an HR guy turn me down for a role because I knew how C#, but he was looking for someone who could code in dotNet.

Comment: @burnt_hand: Yeah, I know dotNet. I also know Excel and Internet Explorer. I can haz contract now?

Comment: While I agree that there are huge overlaps with syntax, structure, SDLC, etc, between Java and C#, if they give you any reasonably tricky C# test in your interview, how will you fare?

Comment: Excellent point, and encountered by many here I suppose. +1.

Comment: +1 Joel says it's the [worst possible way to hire](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/SortingResumes.html)

Comment: A lot of places just aren't hiring someone for ten or twenty years, though.  They're hiring someone for *this project today*.  That's why they're so skill-specific.  And in a sense, they're right; if all they want is someone to do *this project today*, they really do need someone who won't have to make all the first-year mistakes in a new language.

Comment: @Kyralessa - I think that I now know enough about the underlying theory of computing and functions of computers to not make basic errors in any programming language. I can read the documentation. However, something that a language specific hire with limited engineering skills /will/ do is make basic errors in the structure, design, correctness, scalability, reliability and maintainability of the program that will potentially cost large amounts to fix. If you don't lose all your customers due to the low quality of the software in the meantime (assuming your project actually gets anywhere).

Comment: I'm not saying their overall approach is right.  If you hire for *today* and not for *ten or twenty years*, you may get people who may have the technical skills today, but you'll also get high turnover and a complete lack of institutional knowledge (that is, knowledge about your workplace).

Comment: @Kyralessa I changed technologies and programming languages from job to job and sometimes within the same company from project to project. If it's not something completely different and you know at least one or two languages fairly well it is totally possible in less than half a year - probably less than three months. There are transitions that may be harder, but even if you just stay in a job for two years a change in language can be handled by a well-versed programmer.

Answer (score 260):

If you're not typing, you're not working.

I believe zombie blank stares and coffee walks are essential to programmers organising things in their heads.

Comment: @burnt_hand - way under-voted. This is one of the things that drives me nuts, when working for somebody else. Non-programmers tend to think that the most valuable time is spent typing, rather than thinking.

Comment: Page up, page down...page up, page down...

Comment: I'm not paid to type, I'm paid to think. I provide typing as a bonus.

Comment: ["code's compiling"](http://xkcd.com/303/)

Comment: This is why I don't think very highly of online freelancing markets that offer recording "working time" with a screengrabber and a webcam. WTF? If you think my quote is good, why do you care what it is _exactly_ that I do in the time I'm charging for?

Comment: @Alan - didn't even know these existed. That would be truly awful

Comment: "If I had more time to code, I'd write fewer lines." - take off on Abe Lincoln quote.

Comment: It's especially bad when working for sales-type people in industries like construction or retail.

Comment: If you pay me to type you're wasting your money. You can hire a typist that's three times faster at typing for half the cost.

Comment: @Tobias .. I used to say that I had big batch of automated tests running and let the console window running full screen.  It worked fine until they banned the practice of unit testing altogether...  sight...  I need a new job.

Answer (score 158):

that you can speed up a late project, simply by throwing more people at it.

Comment: Ah, from The Mythical Man Month. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month

Comment: Actually, uh, you can. -1  (yeah, behold a myth carrier!)

Comment: We use a colorful saying "You can't put 9 women into a room and make a baby in a month".

Comment: Last week we added 4 people with no project experience to "help" meet an unrealistic schedule. This week's report from the project lead to upper management lists: "Schedule slippage Cause: Reduced efficiency due to learning curve of new team members" and "Recovery Plan: Continuing to add more people where opportunity exists."   Unbelieveable.

Comment: It is STILL true... Sigh.

Comment: I wish all PMs knew this on a mandatory basis.

Comment: This is not a myth, since no one actually believes it. It is now a part of common sense that you can't do this.

Comment: @vetler, you'd be surprised. This still happens at a lot of software companies.

Comment: @Walter, but you can have 9 babies in 9 months and a little-league  baseball team in 7 years.

Comment: I think I agree with Pavel here. This quote was way over-abused. There is some truth to it but you're quoting out of context. -1

Comment: If you're nearly done, then it's true. If you're only just started, then it's not true. Steve McConnell [wrote some good stuff about this](http://www.stevemcconnell.com/ieeesoftware/eic08.htm)

Answer (score 132):

That writing software is easy.

How else do you explain all these projects that run over time and over budget and people (politicians, the media etc.) are still surprised, and customers complain when you tell them that their "small website" (or whatever) will actually take 6 months to develop and cost several thousand dollars (pounds, Euros, [insert currency of choice])

With fuzzy and ever changing requirements I sometimes think that it's amazing that any software ever gets finished!

I know it's a bit more complicated than that ;)

Comment: And this is when they attempt to take the development to cheaper off-shore alternatives.  Only to find out much later that it turned out to be even more expensive.  And less of what they really needed, because of the physical separation and communication challenges between the development team and customer.

Comment: This isn't just a problem amongst managers, but also programmers themselves. The real problem tends to be that time that isn't spent actively writing code is often missed (possibly due to the widespread LOC = productivity quantification myth).

Comment: It's not that the requirements changed, it's just not what they thought they wanted.

Comment: I had someone dismiss programming as "just a bunch of 'if' statements".  OK, maybe it is... in that case, poetry is "just a bunch of words"... movie production is "just a bunch of scenes", etc.

Comment: I've worked for the type of manager who thought the programming bit was the easy part of the job. And no, he didn't have any programming experience himself.

Answer (score 114):

The complexity of the app is directly proportional to the complexity of the UI. By this reasoning, you should be able to build Google or Twitter over a weekend.

Comment: this is true, I could build Twitter and Google over a single weekend. It isn't their software that is complex; for Google, it is their search algorithm (which is more comparable to a code library, or database driver), and Twitter (up until the last 1.5 years) was extraordinarily simple, with only scalability and database issues being complex. Now that it is more complex (requiring more employees), it also has a much more complex UI, and many more UIs.

Comment: I think I read it on Joel Spolsky's blog but the article mentioned only showing as GUI progress in relation to the back-end progress. That way you can give a realistic estimate of progress to the pointy haired guys who are too dumb to understand that most programs consist of a lot more than eye candy.

Comment: 1+ There was a time when I demo'd a SharePoint related project (a multi-lingual addon) to my former boss, having spent hours working on the complex backend code. The end result was not much was done on the UI, which led my boss to believe that not much has been done on the project. That pissed me off. He wasn't the one sitting at the keyboard for hours trying to get around SharePoint's oddities, as well as the text replacement logic.

Comment: Don't you hate when some huge, almost-impossible, request is phrased as "can you add a button to do..."

Comment: I wonder what I have been doing the last few years. All those projects I worked full-time on should have been finished in no time, because they did not have any UI at all. :-)

Answer (score 95):

All programmers are good at math. :-)

Comment: **Commenters:** comments are meant for seeking clarification, not for extended discussion. If you have a solution, leave an answer. If your solution is already posted, please upvote it. If you'd like to discuss this question with others, please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/programmers). See [the FAQ](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

Comment: I think the capabilities in math are somehow related with programming skills.

Comment: @Diego: Although such doesn't necessarily mean all programmers are good at math nonetheless.

Answer (score 95):

Any teenage kid who hacks with computers is equivalent (or superior) in skill to a veteran working programmer.

> My 14 year old nephew is good with
>   computers and I'm paying him $10/hr to
>   mow my lawn. Why should I pay you six
>   figures to write the next FaceBook?

Comment: They probably are in their own environment i.e. working on their own to their own standards. Put them in a team where they have to communicate and that's where they suffer.

Comment: @JohnFx - very true indeed. I have a friend who's son made an iPhone app at 13 using some tool kit, and it's absolutely terrible, hardly works, and is one screen with a list of pictures. He thinks his son is a prodigy.

Comment: Counter question could be:  "What would you pay him to build your house?"

Comment: A kid with no qualifications but writes neat code can beat Mr. Spaghetti any day.

Comment: I blame hollywood for that

Comment: When I started out, I expected that what I'd been teaching myself and picked up at uni would be only the beginning, and I'd be working with more experienced people that were better programmers and more knowledgeable developers, and I'd learn lots from them. Experience taught me otherwise. It's absolutely important, but **without skill and passion, experience is just wasted time.**

Comment: @MAK Wonderful insight.

Answer (score 69):

That **real-time** means fast.

Stating *"The packets need to be processed in real-time."* is worthless and the evil twin...answering *"How fast does X need to happen ?"* with *"Real-time"* is possibly less than worthless...bordering on stupid rather than ignorant.

**Real-time** means that, simply put, that function Y will always take X amount of time and that any deviation indicates a serious error. The duration of X does not define "real-time" it could be six microseconds or six days. That you can **determine** function Y will take X time defines "real-time". Real-time systems are deterministic by this definition.

So knock it off..

Comment: real-time=near-time

Comment: I always thought real-time meant whatever was happening was happening as you require it, not a reference to time taken.

Comment: A good example of a real-time program: iTunes.  When you're playing music, the length of time it takes to play a song is deterministic.

Comment: @burnt_hand The trick is you must specify "as you require it" in units a computer can understand...if you don't then "whatever was happening as you require it" is at whatever rate it happens to be. And that would happen to be unknown. In the context of computers and software "real-time" needs a value.

Comment: Well on real systems fully deterministic execution times are nearly impossible (if it has a CPU cache you're pretty much hosed for totally deterministic, and desktop class CPU's worst case for stuff that's IN MEMORY is an order of magnitude longer than if it's in cache, since we're talking real time I'll assume swap isn't an issue and not even bring up the worst case for that...)

Comment: @spudd86 Uncertainty is required by physics so it will exist and must be accounted for. It is in "hard" real-time systems designed for reliability..like fly-by-wire..where failure impacts life safety. Everything is accounted for cache, memory,etc. in these systems. But this has little to do with my post. My post only concerns the misconception that saying something is "real-time" somehow means that it is fast...it does not. It needs to be quantified. Real-time on W7? Sure. If 4ms of jitter, random >50ms skips meet your spec..then your real-time. Before you say it: real-time doesn't mean safe.

Comment: This is probably just one of those cases where a badly named concept contributes to confusion.

Comment: @JohnFx Well put. Concepts need Context.

Comment: real time is only necessary in systems that require extremely low latency feedback. Ex, motion controls for hydraulic systems and/or mechanical systems, industrial automation, etc. Most of which will be gained using custom hardware, PLC, or industrial specific hardware. The applications of real-time in a PC computing environment are extremely few and far between (which is probably why nobody really understands what it means) and usually require a platform with multiple cores/CPUs to support simultaneous multiprocessing.

Comment: @Richard: Indeed, iTunes always takes a few minutes before playing anything. Oh, that's not what you meant?

Comment: I was raised thinking that soft real-time meant fast enough by guarantee, and hard real-time meant deterministic time slices.  By this definition, the first app I worked on, a reporting system for railroads based on punch cards, was soft real-time because all processing could be done before the train got anywhere else.  That doesn't mean it was fast by modern standards.

Answer (score 69):

Why don't you guys simply write it right the first time, rather than spending so much time typing in buggy code and then later reading the code trying to find the bugs?

:-) :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Frankly, that's a good question. The easiest time to make code good is when it is being written for the first time.

Comment: We have a setting in the app config: <add Key="Bugs" Value="true" />

Comment: @DJClayworth - that doesn't always work.  In some cases, the problem is so large, ill-defined or just plain hard that getting even close to "right" the first time is too much to expect.  In such a case, it is better to write a "first cut" that is not totally wrong, than it is to spend days / weeks / months endlessly designing and redesigning in an attempt to get it right first time.

Comment: This could be the layman's version of "Why aren't you guys doing TDD?" Which, to be fair, is a darn good question, if over-simple for real world development.

Comment: @Stephen C: yes, but there is a difference in getting it mostly right (instead of perfectly right) vs doing mostly anything left and right to just make it work. I know this is not what you said but I still think it need to be said.

Comment: @burnt_hand very enterprisey. I prefer to localise all my bugs into a single `BuggyCode` class using AOP, and instantiate it in my Spring IoC config.

Comment: @Stephen C I agree that writing perfect code the first time in every case is impossible. However most code has bugs in that COULD have been written right the first time. Thinking about why that didn't happen is extremely helpful to improving your software process.

Comment: @Stephen C: Or, you could put some more work into figuring out, and DOCUMENTING, the Requirements for the system you're about to start hacking up.

Comment: All right @John R Strohm - how would documenting the requirement that (say) the compiler you are writing needs to implement type inference over generic types help you get the implementation right first time?  Some systems are TOO DIFFICULT to figure out before you start.  Well, at least for real human beings to figure out.

Answer (score 64):

If you havent gone to university, you are not suitable for the job

Comment: Also: a programmer with a degree is better than a programmer without and should be paid accordingly. The same probably goes with ageism and sexism. This kind of nonsense infuriates me -- if you don't know how to write good code, I couldn't care less about where you went and what you did. This may be another case of programmer/nerd culture (skill == authority) clashing with corporate culture (rank == authority).

Comment: And yet the people teaching at University also seem to think that they can generalize the behavior of programmers and projects by observing how students operate when teamed up. Communications of the ACM is good for 4-6 such articles a year.

Comment: Hmm.... not entirely sure I think this is a myth. It's not because you learn too much about "real programming" in a university -- it's more about the kind of person who goes to a university versus one who does not. The degree doesn't tell you they learned too much, but it does increase the chances of the person you picked giving a shit. Of course that matters less the more experience the individual you are working with has.

Comment: @Billy How about around here, where a college diploma means jack, but a university diploma will grant you everything? Both go to school, both are arguably better than the other, but there's a sociological difference

Comment: @Slokun: What's the difference between "college" and "university" in the above context? As far as I knew they were the same...

Comment: @Billy: in Canada, university awards you a degree and colleges give you diplomas. Colleges are more like "schools where you learn practical stuff". Think community college in the US vs normal college/university. Here they typically have two-year specialized applied programs. You can't get a bachelor's (masters, etc.) from a college. Basically, you'd go to college to study how to write software and to university to study computer science. University degrees are given much stronger preference in hiring.

Comment: @Anna Some are three years, like the one I took (and the extra year was where we learned most of the useful, high-level, information). And actually, some colleges can give out bachelor degrees--or can in Ontario, I can't speak for other provinces--but it's very specific, and quite regulated.

Comment: @Anna + @Solkun: Ah -- I see. I can't comment on the difference between those two, but I do think when looking at new programmers there's significant value in seeing that they at least took some effort to better themselves, whether that's college/university/whatever. It's not so much that I think they'd be inferior programmers -- more so that going to any school is a sign of giving a f*** about your career. If you don't go to school, you know that is not going to bode well for you in the job market. A "I don't care" attitude toward that is a red flag no matter what profession you're in.

Comment: I purposely didnt say post secondary because some private schools are awful. Theres a 18month program that gives you nothing and charge 12k to attend (classes are 5 days a week). I purposely didnt say college because they are typically 2-3years (here) and the people hiring think you MUST have university and college is to start getting into programming. But my answer really was if you dont go to university (as oppose to learn it at home daily for 3+years with proven skill and profolio) you are not suitable for the job. I seen good programmers turned out. It was sad.

Comment: I agree that this is a myth. I know some very clever people who never went to university. But I agree with Joel that [a good way to sort resumes](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/SortingResumes.html) is to look for *evidence that someone has gone through some highly selective process in the past*. Could be getting into a selective university, a selective company, difficult branch of the military. It doesn't *prove* anything one way or another, but it's a good indicator when you have too many resumes and you need to select some for interview/phone screen.

Comment: I have a degree in chemistry. Practically everything I know about code I learned on the job.

Comment: Universities teach at least one important thing: the _mindset_.  This is very important, but those who don't know that... well, don't know that.

Comment: @Billy In my opinion a university degree doesn't really tell you anything about the motivation of a person, especially not whether they care about their career or not. It might be different in Germany, but if someone without a university degree has been able to teach themselves how to write code I would probably be more impressed than if they went to university. I've known people with a university degree in computer science who didn't have a clue and those who didn't have a degree at all and were extremely good at it. In my experience a degree is no indicator at all.

Comment: The person who posted this answer is having difficulty getting employed. I'm not sure how well I'd trust his advice.

Comment: Or the opposite: if you _have_ gone to university, then you are not qualified for the job because you're not a _real_ programmer somehow.  Real programmers dropped out of uni and learned everything they know from coding in their basement, didn't ya know?

Comment: @thomasrutter: I never heard that myth ;)

Comment: @Alan, I hope, that doesn't make you think that a programmer can't learn anything in the university.  They (we) can.  A lot of stuff.  A lot of stuff I see people have troubles formulate and comprehend, let alone to resolve.  And *that's* why the programmers with a degree (we) should be paid better.

Comment: @Pavel: Thats not WHY you have a degree. People who can do that dont need to go to university to gain that ability. In fact someone made me laugh by telling me a highschool kid (who were were talking to) can easily embarrass a few guys he went to university with (who has a degree).

Comment: @Pavel, Oh, I absolutely agree that given two programmers with the same CV, the one with a degree is probably the better one. But the actual benefit for a university education is only apparent in a handful of situations. _Most_ of it can be learned without spending three years writing research papers. The obvious exceptions to this are things like insurance software or physical simulations, although those also require some decent domain knowledge in addition.

Comment: @Alan: Why insurance software? i am sure your not talking about the encryption portion (usually thats done by a library written by a specialist). Why might it be apparent when writing insurance software?

Comment: @acidzombie24 That was really just a random example for the kind of job that would require some solid maths/compsci knowledge. A more realistic one would be working as a performance specialist at Google, but you get the idea. However, the vast majority of programming jobs are more about knowing the right frameworks and libraries and being able to write clean glue code. Heck, the majority of such jobs don't even require any serious optimization. As for your jab: I've met quite a few know-nothings with degrees, so I can back that one up.

Answer (score 61):

That premature optimization means you shouldn't optimize at all. I've seen more horrendously bad databases because no one wanted to consider performance (critical to any database system) in design as that was premature optimization than any other database design issue . Rubbish, there are known performance killers, stop using them as your first choice.

Another myth, it's too hard to refactor the database. No but you have to consider how to do refactoring in the design phase to do it effectively. And BTW, the longer you wait to fix that annoying design-based performance issue, the harder it's going to be to fix.

Another bad myth, database design should reflect OOP principles. No, databases are designed to work with sets not OOP principles. Some OOP things will cause horrible performance problems and others are just pain silly in database terms.

Finally, you should enforce data integrity in the application.  Databases are going to last past the application and would lose the rules when the application is replaced, mulitple applications are going to access them and there will often be the need to run direct queries to fix things that do not go through the application.  I have never seen a database that refuses to enforce data integrity in the datbase that has good data.

Comment: +1 in particular for the comments around database integrity checks.

Comment: +1 Especially for last paragraph. I've beaten that drum more than once.

Comment: +1 for the first paragraph. Premature optimization is the root of all evil; writing bad code for no bloody reason is even worse.

Comment: "Some OOP things will cause horrible performance problems and others are just pain silly in database terms" - could you say which? I know about OOP, but not a lot about databases, and i'm interested in how far i can carry ideas from each side to the other.

Comment: @HLGEM I'd also be interested in the examples @Tom is wondering about...

Comment: AKA "let's do it in Hibernate, it's so easy" myth.

Answer (score 53):

That there is some mythical source of absolute best practices.

No deviation can ever be justified.

No document claiming to define something as a best-practice can ever be questioned.

Comment: I have a developer on my team that thinks like this...

Comment: better a team member than your managers...

Comment: Can you forward that doc to me?

Comment: Totally agree. Who cares if you mix tabs and spaces in Python code?

Comment: @Josh - someone who has to view your source code using a tool chain that has a different idea of where the tab positions are.

Comment: You mean like this? http://dilbert.com/fast/2008-09-03/

Comment: I interpret "it's best practice" as "i can't justify this". I certainly use it that way myself.

Comment: I prefer practices that we require, prefer, use if they make sense, avoid, or prohibit given some context which includes problem domain, solution domain, culture, technology, etc.  "Best" is exceedingly rare and subject to change.

Answer (score 51):

The fact that marketing seems to think that adding a ton of small features is less work than adding a single, but rather heavy, feature.  Which probably is a more specific case of the misconception that "task-switching has no overhead".

Comment: And the even more fun thing of marketing not having any idea which features are easy and which are damned near impossible.

Comment: @derobert Exactly, I have often had the experience that some of the more considerate marketing folks are in fact afraid to even ask about some simple/easy feature which they thought was very difficult to implement. Though I experience the opposite much more oftenly: here's a batch of X "easy" features we've already sold to the customer, please get it done by yesterday....

Answer (score 50):

If we use something other than Java, C# and C++ in our project, we won't find any programmers to support it.

Comment: I never had heard about that, but it's valid. Of course if you use a an obscure language it would happen.

Comment: @bigown, "obscure"?  How obscure?  Is TCL obscure?  Haskell?  Pascal (Delphi)?  Python?  I think they're not obscure.  Many people think they are, and only a very narrow set of languages (C++, C# and Java) are allowed in "serious" development.

Comment: No, I mean very obscure. It's not that case. You're right.

Comment: @bigown: oh, you mean obscure like COBOL? :p

Comment: I once worked for a small company doing Objective-C code on Linux. The CEO - who wasn't an engineer but had some technical knowledge - couldn't believe that there were ObjC programmers around or that anyone else used it. In fact they never had any problems hiring good developers.

Comment: I've read an argument that exactly the opposite is true: for languages which are obscure (or at least commercially insignificant) but cool, fun, and interesting (which in that context meant Python and Ruby), there are more programmers than jobs. Plus, they're all people who are into cool, fun, and interesting languages, so they must be smart. So actually, working in Python means you'll find it easier to hire smart programmers than if you're working in Java. Don't know if i believe it, but it's at least as plausible as the orthodox idea!

Answer (score 50):

That commenting code is unnecessary, or that "good code doesn't need comments". Sometimes you need to explain what a complex bit of code is doing. Furthermore, commenting sections of code helps you skim read much more effectively.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoad - It's true though. The misunderstanding in this "myth" comes from the fact that too many programmers consider their monolithic confusing code to be "good". `if user.is_logged_in: print('Welcome')` doesn't need a comment.

Comment: @orokusaki Not every algorithm is that simple.

Comment: @orokusaki you are mistaking "good code doesn't need comments" with "simple code doesn't need comments". Good code isn't always simple.

Comment: @Jouke van der Mass: of course. But it does not matter how complex the algorithm, the goal is to express the algorithm simply. i.e. good code expresses complex algorithms, rules, optimisations, in a simple and unambigiously understandable way. Expressing simple things simply is comparatively easy. Expressing complex things simply is where the skill lies.

Comment: @orokuskai: good code is simple. The things it is doing may be complex but the simplicity (elegance) of the code is what makes it good in my opinion! Of course, code does lots of other things, and rubbish code can make you lots of money. But my goal is to write simple code even in complex situations.

Comment: @flamingpenguib - well said!

Comment: Comments only help you skim read if they're necessary.  If they're not, they're wasted space.

Comment: "sometimes you need to explain what a complex bit of code is doing" - A hint from an experienced programmer: Your time is better spent simplifying that code.

Answer (score 50):

The worst myth: If you are programming for a long time then you can be a Project Manager easily.

And that you should become a project manager if you have been programming for a long time.

Comment: Or even worse, if you've never programmed or managed a programming project, reading a few books and will magically make software happen. Been down that road with a previous PM and don't care to repeat it as long as I live.

Comment: Even worse:  Since all the great programmers on the team prefer writing code over writing reports, we should promote the mediocre programmer to Project Manager.  The thought is he'll be "tecnical enough".  The fact is he ends up being a disinformation filter between the team and upper managment.

Comment: Also: if you're the best programmer, you should obviously become the project manager and from that point on stop doing any actual programming yourself! No, thank you very much, but I'll still take the raise. Note: I'm not talking about becoming a _lead_ programmer or any such thing, I'm talking about the managers who think it's a clever idea to promote everyone to their level of sufficient incompetence.

Comment: Also known as Peter Principle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Principle

Comment: well said indeed

Comment: I would propose the converse, though: If you don't have any programming experience, you're not qualified to be a project manager for a programming project.

Answer (score 42):

> Java is just C++ with different classes.

Comment: I pity that guy...

Comment: @Rusty Luckily they were only a student.

Comment: +1 I once had an interviewer ask me, "what's the difference between C++ and Java?"  So I listed some differences.  Native compiler vs. JVM, ANSI standard vs. proprietary, garbage collection, classloaders, etc.  He roared, "WRONG!  There's no difference!  They're identical!"  He wasn't a student, he was the engineering manager.

Comment: @Bill, terrible. At least he might have answered some of your own questions about wanting to work for the company.

Comment: @Bill, my response would then be, "then why refer to them with utterly different names?"

Comment: @Bill, so you failed the test and got hired?

Comment: My response would be "Goodbye."

Comment: @Foole Don't you mean System.exit(1) ?

Answer (score 33):

[Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163411/why-did-java-have-the-reputation-of-being-slow) [is](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368/why-do-people-still-say-java-is-slow) [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538156/fileio-in-every-programming-language/3538289#3538289).

Comment: But, to be fair, it did used to be...

Comment: It still is....

Comment: How can coffee be slow ?

Comment: @Rusty Decaf?  .

Comment: Thing is it still is sometimes, and it's memory model is inherently bloated (in several ways, GC has an overhead in memory usage, real resident set size too not just address space, and jars/dynamic compilation mean code is in memory once for every process that is running it) So yes Java can sometimes be very fast, it isn't always, and that's not counting the times that the lack of Plain Old Data types wastes both time and space. And when it's slow, it's REALLY slow.

Comment: @Joe Thanks dude. I knew there had to be something...or why post about it ?

Comment: That's just trash-talk because C++ programmers are envious for the Java coders for getting all the girls (...I wish).

Comment: “Knock, knock.” — “Who’s there?” — *very long pause…* “Java.” (Courtesy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke/234138#234138)

Comment: Java is just a slow starter.  We'll catch up in a day or two.

Comment: See http://blip.tv/file/319044/. It takes a generation to change people's perceptions. Java is will always be considered slow as long as it's called Java.

Comment: I used to think that "Java is not slow anymore" until I saw the same pricing algorithm implemented in C++, running orders of magnitude quicker.

Comment: All the JVM implementations that I know of *are* slow to start up, and for that reason I refuse to use any JVM language (for application development). Working in an environment which imposes a human-perceptable pause before even *beginning* to execute your code is painfully constrictive. Yes, I know about nailgun, and Project Jigsaw, but it is unreasonable to expect that an end user would be running either a non-standard background Java server or an unreleased version of Java. Of course, slow startup might be OK for a server, and nailgun might be OK for in-house scripting.

Answer (score 33):

Probably the most dangerous one I've seen, because it gets accepted so readily, is that being able to write code quickly is good, and therefore the more quickly you can code [insert feature here] in a given language, the better the language is.

This is a serious example of premature optimization, since far more work goes into *maintaining* code than creating it.  This means that it's much more important to write code that's easy to read, comprehend and debug than code that's easy to write quickly, and facilitating easy-to-read code is a much more useful measurement of language quality.

Comment: this is precisely what happened to one of the products the company I work for; rushed development was seen as brilliant. The product LOOKED ok and the developer was highly praised by upper management.
Another junior developer was then tasked with fixing a "small" bug, and after a week of trying to understand the code, gave up and sought guidance from a senior.. who couldn't believe how rubbish the code was. Upper management refused to accept is as a major issue for two years, after which the eventually agreed it was a pile of junk and needed to be coded again from scratch - and right this time

Comment: There's a well-established myth among technical managers that your skilled developers are ten times more productive than unskilled developers. The direct result of this myth is that any developer who can produce code *quickly* -- regardless how buggy or hard to maintain -- gets praise and promotion.

Comment: @rtperson: http://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots0725.html Second panel.

Comment: You _NEED_ a powerful language.  See Paul Grahams discussion of languages and what ti enables you to do: http://www.paulgraham.com/power.html

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I've read that article, and Paul Graham has it wrong.  He's a Lisp advocate, so  he twists the facts into self-serving arguments to make Lisp look good.  Maybe not even conciously, since it really doesn't take much twisting.  There's a lot of overlap between readability and succinctness, as he points out towards the end of the article.  But the conclusions he draws are completely out of sync with the state of software development in the real world.  Yes, you need a powerful language, but he's measuring power by the wrong criteria, and it's harmful to believe what he says.

Comment: @Mason - I agree with Paul Graham that languages have different levels of power (I have not decided on the Lisp conclusion yet).  Just try doing in BASIC what Perl can do with a regexp oneliner to a textfile...

Comment: @rtperson:  That productivity can vary by a factor of ten is no myth.  That people who finish fast are necessarily more productive is.

Comment: The correct version of this myth would be that being able to write *good* code quickly is good.  A minimum of [syntactic noise](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/SyntacticNoise.html) helps to achieve that end.

Comment: @Mason, if the metric was "how fast you can write PRODUCTION code" it is actually quite reasonable.

Comment: The major thing wrong with PG's "Beating the Averages" argument is he undermines the role his Harvard Engineering PhD might have played in the success of his company. Instead, it was all the magic of Lisp. It's as if an Olympic weightlifter responded to the question "How do you clean lift 500 lbs?" with the answer, "Wear this shirt!"

Comment: Fast development is has no correlation to sloppy code. And slow development does not imply it is good. You can be fast/good. fast/bad. slow/good. slow/bad.

Answer (score 31):

Manufacturing lessons can be applied to the software development process.

Comment: Depends on the lessons. When I worked at a mattress factory, we learned that task-switching was harmful to our production. Kinda important since we were paid by the number of mattresses made and not by the hour... and a lesson that applies here too for a lot of the same reasons.

Comment: This is such a persistent myth when you work in a place that mostly makes hardware.   The hoops we jump through to fit our software 'build' into the same model as a hardware 'part' are amazing...

Comment: Thing is, manufacturing software is trivial.  It's easy to make copies, and doesn't cost all that much to make millions of copies.  This leads people to ignore the manufacturing part altogether, and try to apply manufacturing to the design process.

Comment: +100 for this, especially people that studied economics think this

Comment: Everyone should read Jack Reeves: http://www.developerdotstar.com/mag/articles/reeves_design_main.html - this is the origin (or at least an early and powerful statement) of the idea that source code is a *design* not a *product*. Programmers are like the designers in the drafting room, not the machinists on the factory floor, and the management of programming must be like the management of other kinds of engineering design, not manufacturing.

Comment: +1 for that.... a software and a film studio should never be a factory

Comment: Best analogy I've come across is that software development is design, and the compiler is manufacturing.

Comment: The one manufacturing lesson I think is good for software is that quality can't be an afterthought, but must be designed into the system.

Answer (score 31):

that as a programmer you know everything about latest hardware trends, overclocking, case mod, etc. friends and relatives consult you when they buy their gears.

Comment: I used to keep on top of some of these things back in highschool, but nowadays I find that they are generally irrelevant to what I do and while some are neat, I'd much rather pay someone who knows their stuff and use the time I save doing what I like (i.e. writing code). Maybe another "good with computers" misunderstanding.

Comment: +1, or a slightly one off tangent - Because your a programmer, you have a super duper water cooled 300 LED fan spinning flashing top of the range brand new shipped from the manufacturing plant before its been released case. Erm not really! Its a decently fast machine, its in a black very cheap case. Dont really care beyond that!

Comment: Laugh, there's a PM assistant at work who has some god-almighty gaming rig at home, always rolls over to the Dev area to ask if he should buy (Product A) or (Product B) ... in an unrelated note, he also assumes the dev team all hang out on 4Chan, (which he actually does.) - *sigh*

Comment: +1 Word. This is spot on. I'm a software developer and I've been asked to configure someone's internet for so many times and basically all I do is trial and error plus Google searches. I like it best when something completely unrelated breaks after you've done someone a favour and then it's your fault.

Answer (score 30):

That when programmers say it's very hard to do/simply impossible, HR thinks they're lazy and unmotivated

Comment: Include management too

Comment: When you say no they think you're simply a difficult person to work with.

Comment: +100, and that with enough "motivation", they can change your answer. Or go to another [less experienced] developer and purposefully leave out half the details to get him to say yes, only to end up halfway thru development and bump into the exact problem you warned them about.

Answer (score 28):

There must be an open source program for my business. Can't you just download it and tweak to my requirements.

Comment: +1. Oh, yes, whatever we need to do must already be in open source.

Comment: a lot of the time there is... at least thats true for web development.

Comment: @WalterJ89: It may be there, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea to use it. Open source doesn't automatically mean good code.

Comment: true.. but in the case of Wordpress, Drupal, jQuery, ...
there may be areas where free is not great, like e-Commerce but more often than not the web is very open,  and I find I enjoy working with an open source community far more than a propietory help desk.

Comment: The opposite is a myth too. That you cannot use FOSS to satisfy your business needs.

Answer (score 27):

I've had more than one person ask me about what it is like to program only to realize midway through the conversation that they actually think we program directly in binary or using mathematical symbols.

I don't know if I want to dispel that myth, it makes me look really smart!

Comment: It doesn't help that most people don't even know what programming really is... they have this vague idea that it's creating software... but they don't really have a clear idea what software is...

Comment: "We write knitting recipes".   Grandmothers tend to understand that.

Comment: I know people who will write a program in C, then redo the most performance-critical parts in Assembly.

Comment: @Josh - unless there is a performance problem, that seems like a waste of time.

Comment: @JohnFx: When coding for uControllers it's often necessary to recode some things in assembly, either to deal with idiosyncracies of the hardware or because the compiler optimizes necessary elements out of the executable.

Comment: @oosterwal - Assembly is not binary, nor does it use mathematical symbols.

Comment: @JohnFx:  Here's an example of what I'm talking about:  `// if (A2D_UNCALIBRATED)          // If not calibrated`
`_asm("ld  a,_A2D_UNCALIBRATED"); // Must write the if/else in assembly otherwise`
`_asm("jreq    A2D_CALIBRATED");  // the compiler will optimize out the code (due to ROM Constant).`
`{`

Comment: @oosterwal - There wasn't a single 1 or 0 in your example. Still not getting your point. You do know that Assembly code is higher level than machine code (binary) right?

Comment: @JohnFx: My first comment was reflecting back on @Josh's comment about recoding parts of C in Assembly.  You had mentioned that, unless there were serious performance issues that it seemed like a waste of time.  I only wanted to point out that there are times, like when a compiler optimizes critical C statements out of the code, that you have to rewrite parts of the C source in Assembly.  I didn't think I had mentioned anything about machine language or binary, but if I did, please accept my apologies for causing confusion.

Answer (score 26):

I think the biggest misconception is that it's more important being able to write the code down easily than being able to read and understand the code.

Comment: *v(int)(void)++

Comment: @Rusty: I can come up with much, *much* worse examples if I don't even have to be syntactically correct.

Comment: Ahh, yes, "Write only" code...

Answer (score 24):

Programming is just like assembly line work. You are working on a product for a certain time (maybe with coworkers) and finally you ship it. Just like building a house of bricks.

> Contra: Programming contains a lot creativity and planning. It is art. Like the mason, also a programmer knows the difference between shaping a brick and planning a whole cathedral.

Comment: Agree about difference from assembly line work -- but in many ways I don't think it's much different from building a house.

Answer (score 24):

Porting a program to C++ will automatically make it run faster.

Comment: I would extend to another low level languages. It's possible get the opposite when the programmer doesn't know what it is doing.

Comment: Another common variant is switching to a client-server architecture. "Upgrading to SQL will make my app much faster!" Not necessarily.

Comment: Yes, it's quite the opposite many times. SQL kind databases are good to be ACID or almost that, it comes with price. And could be worst, the wrong thinking about SQL techniques could be harmful about performance.

Comment: Porting to C++/C for those written in Python/Perl/Ruby/etc. Porting to asm for those written in C/C++ :P. I wonder what you'd port asm to? designing it into the hardware?

Comment: I love that one! ;-)

Comment: +1 -- true. That said, porting to **ideomatic** C++ probably will make it run faster (but is by no means automatic)

Comment: especially bad when your boss thinks this

Comment: @MAK - check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handel-C

Answer (score 21):

Any programming environment with a visual designer of some sort will make it so that business users can "write" the program and actual programmers aren't needed.

Comment: Ah, yes. It's always fun when some company creates a new authoring tool to make programmers redundant and then everybody who adopts it goes ahead and hires highly-paid <authoring tool> specialists to actually use it. Case in point: Joomla! and all that non-sense.

Comment: HA HA HA HA HA  HAAA HA +1 :)

Comment: Cobol already tried that :)

Answer (score 20):

OOP reuse. It's the biggest fallacy marketed in programming.

Comment: Well. The HP XL WESM is roughly 85% the same as the Symbol WS5100 (there's OEMming going on). Would you have me copy-and-paste that percentage of my monitoring and configuration code so that there's twice as many bugs, or would you prefer that I rewrite it from scratch and take forty times as long and there are five times as many? Or are you just pressured by foolish management which thinks that it's one of several magical panaceas to make $project faster?

Comment: Reuse in the small was solved 40 years ago and more. Reuse in the large is difficult and hasn't been solved yet IMHO. Just like Robert Glass says in [Facts and fallacies of software engineering](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Facts-Fallacies-Software-Engineering-Development/dp/0321117425)

Answer (score 19):

That learning the syntax is the hard part.

Answer (score 15):

That assigning a priority other than "1" means the task will never be done.

I had a manager ask me to customize the bug-tracking tool with priorities 1a, 1b, 1c, 1d, and 1e so he could assign everything as some variation of priority 1, but we could still organize the work.

And yes, I did get through all the "priority 1" issues.  But before I could proceed to the issues that were still in priority 2-5, the manager made me re-assign the priorities of those issues into the five priority 1 levels.

(I realize this myth isn't *specific* to programming, but that's true of several other answers on this thread.)

Comment: You mean you didn't subdivide the `1a` priority level into 1a.0, 1a.1, 1a.2, and 1a.3 ... and then the 1a.0 into 1a.0.0 and 1a.0.1 and 1a.0.2 ... that's just crazy! ;-D

Comment: I didn't work with that manager long enough, but I don't doubt it would have come to that!

Comment: I like to keep things simple: high, medium, low. Imagine my (non-)surprise when the business user classified a bunch as medium-high.

Comment: You might as well classify them as *top*, *tippy-top*, and *critical*.

Comment: I used to be given a number 1 priority and then about a half hour later a .5 priority!

Comment: @Jesse: ABC curve always worked.

Comment: Prioritizing is tricky, but some people are worse than others. There's always one person on a team that thinks a minor spelling mistake in a error dialog box on a dusty old page is **'Critical'**.

Comment: "If everything is important, then nothing is important"

Comment: Raymond Chen blogged about [priority inflation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/11/21/9131198.aspx) at Microsoft.

Comment: very well said Sergio.

Comment: but this one goes up to 11

Answer (score 15):

2 myths I want to have revealed. A lot of my friends do not understand that Java and JavaScript are completely different, and a lot of non-programmers I know don't understand that there is more than one language. One of my friends was just getting into programming and needed some help from me, 'course he didn't even know what language he was working in.

Those both come up a lot for me.

Comment: I love this quote: "Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet."  I've read this attributed to Chris Heilmann (http://www.wait-till-i.com/2005/11/08/do-hr-people-even-read-their-job-ads-when-they-get-published/)

Comment: Java doesn't contain JavaScript, but hopefully your car has carpets.

Comment: My computer science professor told us, at the very end of the semester, that since he taught us Java, he also taught us JavaScript. I cried myself to sleep.

Comment: @Bill - I've heard a similar one... "Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Caravan, they both have wheels, but otherwise they're very different."

Comment: @configurator: Actually, [Sun's implementation of Java 6 is co-bundled with the Mozilla Rhino JavaScript engine](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsengine).  So modern Java does come with JavaScript, but just like the Carpets in your Car, it's an often-overlooked detail.

Answer (score 13):

As long as the computer understands the code you type in, that's all that matters.
Therefore typing in comments and using variable names that are more than two letters long is a waste of time. :-(

Comment: And who cares if your code looks like Spaghetti?

Answer (score 12):

Keyboarding form is related to programming ability.  Seriously, one of the teachers at my high school told me, "You can't code quickly if you can't type quickly."  My response was, "That's like saying I can only write the Great American Novel if I do it in cursive."

Comment: +1  Being able to type quickly actually can help sometimes.  But being able to think clearly HELPS A WHOLE HELL OF A LOT MORE.

Comment: You can't code quickly if you're a hunt-and-peck typist.

Comment: There is a good point in there: being proficient in typing means you don't interrupt your thoughts to hunt and peck.  (You'll be more likely to use better variable names, too.)  The only problem here is "quickly"; being able to type normal prose at 60wpm should be plenty, but isn't very fast.

Comment: @quanticle - This is true though. Make a Venn diagram; draw a circle for "fast typing", and then put a tiny circle inside that one labeled, "good programming".

Comment: As with anything, this has been covered by Scott Adams: http://thedilbertstore.com/images/periodic_content/dilbert/dt940608dhc0.jpg?1252609186

Comment: Hunt-and-peck typing a 100'000 line program?  It _IS_ hampering your programming ability.  Learn touch typing.

Comment: Why are people taking this to extremes? I don't touch type, but I don't hunt-and-peck either. I program just fine thankyou, even if I only manage about 50-60WPM. Much more than that will just be bottlenecked by your brain. We aren't taking dictation, we are creating.

Comment: I learnt to touch type, but actually prefer to type with four fingers.

Comment: As any other basic ability, I want to be able to type so comfortably I don't have to think on what I'm doing... If typing gets on your way to program, you've got a problem...

Comment: Covered by Steve Yegge too: http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2008/09/programmings-dirtiest-little-secret.html

Comment: Being able to type reasonably accurately without thinking about it is good.  Speed doesn't matter nearly as much.

Answer (score 12):

That the prototypical programmer:

- comes in to work after 11am
- drinks nothing but Mountain Dew
- loves indian food or sushi
- lives alone by choice (with parents and/or in basement)
- stays up until 3am playing video games

Comment: It's a stereotype for a reason...

Comment: @Kelly - every bit of this is true.

Comment: What?  those are not true?

Comment: At least 3 of those apply to me!

Comment: Not true.  I hate sushi.

Comment: This isn't all that far off.  I'm a gamer who loves indian food _AND_ sushi =)  I wish I could come into work after 11 though.

Comment: nope, nope, nope, nope, *i wish!*

Comment: A score of less than 3 means you're not a real programmer.

Comment: i wish, nope, nope, nope, yep

Comment: point 1 - no, but I should since most requests come after 4:30pm.  point 2 - guilty.  point 3 - guilty.  point 4 - nope, wife and kids and dogs.  point 5 - no, stay up until 3am watching sci-fi.

Comment: well, let's see.  I come in every day ~9AM.  I hate Mountain Dew, Indian food *and* sushi.  I live alone, (alone, not with parents) but only because I haven't found The One yet, so not exactly by choice.  And I'll frequently stay up until 11 PM playing video games, but 3 AM? That's just crazy.

Comment: I cannot believe this -- surely every *true* programmer drinks nothing but Coca-Cola (the original version, no "light" or "diet" thing).

Comment: Well, he (or she) lives alone by lack of choice :-D

Comment: You have defined the **stereotypical** programmer. You are objecting to this definition being that of a **typical** programmer. **Prototypes** do not come into this.

Comment: @Josh: Maybe the prototype was that way; that would explain a lot.

Comment: I must admit that I do like sushi, occasionally.

Comment: And I like Indian food, but that is the only one that applies, but hey I'm 47!

Comment: Those are not the worse stereotype I saw associated with programming but I agree that there seems to exist a lot of stereotypes about programmers and they need to go. I really hates most of them for the reason that they rarely fit me at all (if not being the total opposite!).

Comment: Man, I wish I could be up and play games to 3am in the morning. That'd be awesome! Unfortunately I have a job to do. :C

Answer (score 10):

Bug free software. Later I came to know that every program would still run with Bugs and whole play was about accomplishing customer Requirements.

Comment: Very true. The goal isn't bug free software, it is software with the bugs removed that are worth the cost of finding/fixing.

Comment: @JohnFx - that is if you don't mind giving IT managers heart problems.

Comment: I'm  pretty sure I can write a bug-free hello world.

Comment: the fact that it is possible to create a program that is only a few lines without any bugs means it is POSSIBLE to create bug free software, however John is right, we will only spend the time ($) doing it if it's necessary, not only for the sake of it's own value, but even more for the value of other things that need our attention, hence it is not a myth

Comment: This is definitely true. The problem is that most managers think bugs == sloppy craftsmanship and expect you to be able to say that the software is _guaranteed_ to be bug-free if you did your job properly. This may be a manager/programmer jargon problem though: in manager speak "this program works" is usually equivalent to programmer speak "I'm confident that this program works". Programmers tend to avoid absolutes like that for a reason.

Comment: NASA goes for bug-free software, and comes surprisingly close.  It's extremely expensive, of course, and takes an awful long time to write anything.

Comment: @David Any evidence for the expense and the slowness? I'm sure I've read they have industry-average productivity, but ten times fewer bugs than average. They win awards too.

Comment: From what I've read about NASA, they don't have industry-average productivity.  Everything I've read has noted slowness and cost.  Where have you encountered anything to the contrary?

Answer (score 10):

That Hungarian notation only means that you prefix variable names with a type (like int iArraylength = 5; ) instead of what kind of data it holds (like int xcTextfield = getTextfield().coord.x; )

"Systems Hungarian notation" != "Apps Hungarian notation"

Comment: both are still an abomination in a strongly typed language

Answer (score 9):

That any code written in an OOP (C#, C++, Java) language by anyone is automatically Object Oriented and "Reusable".

It wasn't just once where I was asked to reuse a thousand line code block or a class in an architecture that did not have any patterns except inheritance (which doesn't even count). Apparently, copy pasting also counts as good code-reuse for anyone who doesn't know the difference between an OO-language and OOP itself.

A favorite TDWTF that's happens every so often: [Code-Refuse](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Code-Refuse.aspx)

Answer (score 9):

That web apps can be up "7x24."

Ask any business person what downtime is allowed and they always insist on 100% uptime. Nevermind that 1 minute downtime per week is still 99.99% and is nearly unachievable for an organization smaller than a major utility.

Comment: "We need 5 nines!!!" No...no, you don't. People know how to hit 'refresh'. And if you're worried about lost sales...well, if your profit margin is 0.001%, rethink your business plan.

Comment: @Alex Feinman you'd be amazed how many people *don't* know how to hit refresh.

Answer (score 7):

The biggest myth is that it's easy.

Answer (score 7):

That there is a single "best" tool/solution/answer to any problem/question

Answer (score 7):

All programs written in C/C++ will execute faster than Java/C# equivalent programs.

Answer (score 6):

That any M.Sc. with one programming course is enough to be hired as a software developer.

Comment: I've got a colleague with a degree in psychology. That seems to have been good enough, he's a very capable software developer. And I don't have a degree at all.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. I guess your colleague was hired because he knew how to program, not for his degree in psychology. A M.Sc. with one programming course that has been programming for ten years is not a problem either. When this programming course is the -only- programming they have done, then it is not enough. And math skills do not automatically make you produce good, fast, stable, maintainable code. Usually some other programmer has to fix the mess.

Comment: I have a degree in philosophy with 1 programming course. I taught myself the rest that I needed for the job and work as a software developer and I keep up with people who have CS degrees and have 10 years of experience. I'm no wiz and would probably be better if i had a CS degree, but I have been able to get by through practice and study. (of course, philosophy did prepare me with much more formal logic than most and that definitely contributed).

Answer (score 6):

That because you are a programmer, you know how to fix the copier.

Comment: But I *do* know how to fix the copier!

Comment: Programmers are by nature problem-solving beings who can take in large amounts of information and reason about it.  That makes them probably better at average at fixing things.  It doesn't help my house plants, though.  I now mostly ignore them, let my wife take care of them, and don't think too hard at them, just in case.

Comment: To me every copier looks like a nail and I'm the hammer.

Answer (score 6):

Programmers who became managers saying:

> **"Three weeks?! I've coded in the past, how *hard* can it be?"**

Answer (score 4):

Computers and software improve working process by itself.

Answer (score 4):

> Which wrong ideas are widespread for long time

There is a very widespread belief among programmers about how to find performance problems. It is that **in order to find them, you have to measure them**.

The simplest counter-example is an (undesired) infinite loop. It takes 100% of time, doing things that are completely unnecessary.

How do you find the problem? You get it under a debugger and pause, halt, or interrupt it. Then you look at the stack, because you know the loop is somewhere on it. *You've caught it in the act.* Did you measure it? or just find it?

Suppose it's not an infinite loop, it just takes longer than you think necessary.
Suppose the unnecessary work is less than 100%, like 90%, 50%, or 20%. It's the same idea. If you pause it, that percent is the chance that you will catch it in the act. (You don't have to know what the percent is to catch it.)

Just to be sure, you can pause it several times. As soon as you see it doing something, on as few as **two** samples, that you can replace with something faster, you can fix it for a nice speedup.
Not only that, you've just made any other problems easier to find, because the time is shorter and they take a bigger percent. This can "snowball" until the code is very close to optimal.

Of course, if you *want* to measure the problem, just take more samples, but that's not a prerequisite to finding it.

People tell me, wishfully, that this is what sampling profilers do but do it better. Many would rather debate the issue than see for themselves.

Comment: Nice subject for an answer. I'm feeling pedantic: I say you are still measuring, it's just a rough measurement.

Comment: @MarkJ: Well, OK, if you insist. I'm just trying to knock folks out of their rut where they believe rather than thinking. Another think I like to say is it doesn't matter *where* a program "spends its time", but *why*.

Comment: "this is what sampling profilers do but do it better" is 100% correct. Why don't you just run a profiler and optimize the slowest subroutine, then repeat? It's no more effort once you've installed the profiler.

Comment: Also, an infinite loop is not a "performance problem", it's a straight-up bug.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: 1) You could say there is a world of difference between something that takes 10^N times longer than it should, and something that never ends. In my world, they both take too long, and can be found by the same means. 2) The idea that performance problems consist of slow subroutines is not correct, in my experience. This could be a long discussion, but [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387895/if-profiler-is-not-the-answer-what-other-choices-do-we-have/4390868#4390868).

Answer (score 4):

That being a manager is better then being a coder.  Being a manager is BORING.  Anybody who went into pure management has never loved programming to begin with.

Comment: Haha, so right +1 my friend!

Answer (score 3):

That a manager knows jack-squat about the code that his/her developers are writing.

Comment: This may be a myth in your office, it's reality in mine.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "manager". The project lead usually knows the code pretty well. Just one level higher and all knowledge about the details of the source code go out the door.

Answer (score 3):

Among programmers: That Delphi is dead, dying or on life support.

Comment: That's very sweet of you ;-)

Comment: Do you guys use Delphi?

Comment: Is good old Delphi still breathing? Now nice....

Comment: More wishful thinking than myth I'd say. I have worked a little on some legacy pieces of Delphi and I can't say that I wish for Delphi more than a quick death. Double declaration, brrr, implicit 'begin's, ugh.

Answer (score 3):

There is a language called C/C++

Or that the languages are so close that skills are interchangeable.

Comment: +1 but at the same time some seem to think that any use of C/C++ as a phrase is wrong. how are you meant to refer to their common subset?

Comment: @jk01: Yes syntactically they have a common subset. But knowing this is not enough. The style used by both languages is now so divergent that they don't translate.

Answer (score 2):

That writing software is actually about writing code.

Comment: +1 I would phrase it a little bit differently and say that there's a huge difference between developing (releasable) software and writing code. Some people might be good or even great at programming, but have little discipline to deliver releasable and maintanable code. It's when there's neither unit tests nor documentation nor an acceptable test script that you know something is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Many people tend to think that JavaScript is similar to C++ and don't understand that it actually uses prototype inheritance.

Comment: It uses more than just prototype inheritance.

Comment: @orokusaki - That's true. It also uses the unpasteurized blood of newborn babies. ;)

Comment: '' == '0' //false 0 == '' // true parseInt('010') // returns 8! (in FF3)

Answer (score 1):

That programming languages change all the time.

This might have been a long time ago in the past...
But nowadays the changes are mostly extra features which try not to break existing code.

Comment: the DISTANT past... like pre-1970...

Comment: this is a myth only for static-type language programmers (i.e. Java, C, C++, etc) which are thousands of years old and require a doctorates degree to be taken seriously at. If you use Ruby or Python, you know that things to change quickly, to make programming easier so that software development can transcend obfuscation.

Comment: @orokusaki: True, but with Python et al. you'll often find that "new" versions are supported alongside "old" ones (e.g. Python 2 and 3, PHP 4 and 5) and often the underlying code will be forward-compatible (e.g. all of Python 2.x to 2.7). Many dynamic languages make sure only to break compatibility in major releases and are quite careful not to do so too frequently.

Answer (score 0):

Why do programmers insist on writing bugs? (Coming from a marketing+tester person that can never get a bug report done right).

Answer (score 0):

Using English (or your native language) to describe a problem:

is more useful than providing a compilable example of the code the illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- That OO means quality.
- That the OO approach is the right
  approach.
- That the job of a programmer is to
  write code.
- That language matters.

Answer (score 0):

The whole **hollywood mentality** (for lack of a better name) that whenever a programmer in a movie/tv series speaks up he needs to articulate every technology he needs (*I need a PHP front-end and a MySQL back-end!!!11*)... And then some more that doesn't make any sense at all of course.

If I would talk like this I'd probably get kicked in the nuts.

Answer (score -1):

Good Programmer if you spend more time on programming.Practice makes a person perfect  but doesnt make him good.

Answer (score -6):

That comments are actually useful

Comment: I think you meant the opposite ...

Comment: Let's rephrase that as "That comments are inherently useful", because that is obviously blatantly wrong. Comments can even be misleading or disruptive. Ideally code should be self-explanatory. Comments should only be used to add non-obvious details or explain complex code that can't be refactored into a more readable version (e.g. because doing so would be seriously inefficient or impossible).

Comment: Totally agree. In fact overuse/incorrect of comments I would consider harmful.